# Como converter um tipo varchar de uma coluna para datetime dentro de uma view usando SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Eu tenho uma view com uma coluna de tipo varchar e estou querendo converter essa coluna para um tipo date time o meu código está aqui:

```
update temp_vertical_dashboard
set data = convert (datetime,data,101)
```

temp_vertical_dashboard é a minha view e data é a coluna dentro da minha view.
quando executo me da erro.Alguém sabe como me ajudar nesse aspecto por favor?

Comment: Qual banco de dados?

Comment: Obrigado por responder Camilo.é Sql server

Comment: `cast(data as datetime)`

Comment: @Marconi pode me dizer a função específico desse "CAST" e tbm gostaria de saber usando isso qual tipo de formato vai me dar?

Comment: o cast vai retornar o que estiver depois de "as", com isso vai te dar datetime

Comment: @Kelvin `convert (datetime,data)` sem o '101' funciona também. Dá uma olhada [CAST](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

Comment: @Marconi tentei fazer desse jeito update temp_vertical_dashboard set data = convert(datetime,data) e me deu Mensagem 4406, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 3
Falha ao atualizar ou inserir a exibição ou a função 'temp_vertical_dashboard' porque ele contém um campo derivado ou constante.

Comment: Obrigado @Emerson pela explicação vou tbm ir profundo um pouco pesquisando sobre isso.

Comment: Até agora tudo que eu tentei me faz aparecer essa mensagem:Ç Mensagem 4406, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 3
Falha ao atualizar ou inserir a exibição ou a função 'temp_vertical_dashboard' porque ele contém um campo derivado ou constante.

Comment: @Kelvin fiz uma pergunta aqui sobre: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/214275/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-cast-e-convert

Comment: @Marconi boa! vou ver ver as resposta do pessoal para ter mais ideá sobre o assunto

Comment: Veja este [SOpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015122/convert-date-format-to-sql-server-function)

Comment: @Ivan Ferrer, qual parâmetro eu passo dentro do getdate()? e essa query só vai listar,mas preciso que faz  um update convertendo a minha coluna do tipo varchar para datetime. Talvez expliquei errado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tudo vai depender do formato da sua data. Com o formato 101 você está especificando que o formato é `mm/dd/aaaa`. O código abaixo retorna a data `21/06/2017`:

```
DECLARE @data varchar(10) = '06/21/2017';

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @data, 101);
```

Caso esteja usando o formato brasileiro você deve utilizar o código 103 para a conversão:

```
DECLARE @data varchar(10) = '21/06/2017';

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @data, 103);
```

---

Você não pode fazer um update diretamente na sua `view`, então você deve alterar a definição da mesma para algo como abaixo:

```
ALTER VIEW temp_vertical_dashboard AS (
  SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, t.data, 101) AS data
    FROM tabela t
)
```

---

Na documentação [**CAST e CONVERT (Transact-SQL) - Estilos de data e hora**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187928.aspx#Anchor_4) conferir os códigos correspondentes à conversões de data.

Conversões disponíveis:

```
╔═════════════════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Sem século (AA) ║ Com século (aaaa) ║ Standard                          ║ Entrada/saída (3)                      ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 0 ou 100 (1,2)    ║ Padrão para datetime e            ║ mês dd aaaa hh:miAM (ou PM)            ║
║                 ║                   ║ smalldatetime                     ║                                        ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1               ║ 101               ║ EUA                               ║ 1 = mm/dd/aa                           ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 101 = mm/dd/aaaa                       ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 3               ║ 103               ║ Britânico/francês                 ║ 3 = dd/mm/aa                           ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 103 = dd/mm/aaaa                       ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 4               ║ 104               ║ Alemão                            ║ 4 = dd.mm.aa                           ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 104 = dd.mm.aaaa                       ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 5               ║ 105               ║ Italiano                          ║ 5 = dd-mm-aa                           ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 105 = dd-mm-aaaa                       ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 6               ║ 106 (1)           ║ -                                 ║ 6 = dd mês aa                          ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 106 = dd mês aaaa                      ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 7               ║ 107 (1)           ║ -                                 ║ 7 = Mês dd, aa                         ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 107 = Mês dd, aaaa                     ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 8               ║ 108               ║ -                                 ║ hh:mi:ss                               ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 9 ou 109          ║ Padrão + milissegundos            ║ mês dd aaaa hh:mi:ss:mmmAM (ou PM)     ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 10              ║ 110               ║ EUA                               ║ 10 = mm-dd-aa                          ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 110 = mm-dd-aaaa                       ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 11              ║ 111               ║ JAPÃO                             ║ 11 = aa/mm/dd                          ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 111 = aaaa/mm/dd                       ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 12              ║ 112               ║ ISO                               ║ 12 = aammdd                            ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 112 = aaaammdd                         ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 13 ou 113         ║ Padrão Europa + milissegundos     ║ dd mês aaaa hh:mi:ss:mmm (24h)         ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 14              ║ 114               ║ -                                 ║ hh:mi:ss:mmm(24h)                      ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 20 or 120 (2)     ║ ODBC canônico                     ║ aaaa-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)               ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 21 or 121 (2)     ║ ODBC canônico (com milissegundos) ║ aaaa-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)               ║
║                 ║                   ║ padrão para hora, data, datetime2 ║                                        ║
║                 ║                   ║ e datetimeoffset                  ║                                        ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 126 (4)           ║ ISO8601                           ║ aaaa-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm (sem espaços)  ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║                                        ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ Observação: Quando o valor de          ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ milissegundos (mmm) for 0, o valor de  ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ milissegundos não é exibido. Por       ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ exemplo, o valor                       ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ '2012-11-07T18:26:20.000' é exibido    ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ como '2012-11-07T18:26:20'.            ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 127(6, 7)         ║ ISO8601 com fuso horário Z.       ║ aaaa-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmmZ (sem espaços) ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║                                        ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ Observação: Quando o valor de          ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ milissegundos (mmm) for 0, o valor de  ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ milissegundos não é exibido. Por       ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ exemplo, o valor                       ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ '2012-11-07T18:26:20.000' é exibido    ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ como '2012-11-07T18:26:20'.            ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 130 (1, 2)        ║ Hijri (5)                         ║ dd mmm aaaa hh:mi:ss:mmmAM             ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║                                        ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ Neste estilo, mon representa uma       ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ representação unicode Hijri de vários  ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ tokens do nome completo do mês. Este   ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ valor não será renderizado corretamente║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ em uma instalação US padrão do SSMS.   ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 131 (2)           ║ Hijri (5)                         ║ dd/mm/aaaa hh:mi:ss:mmmAM              ║
╚═════════════════╩═══════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

- (1) esses valores de estilo retornam resultados não determinísticos. Incluem todos os estilos (aa) (sem século) e um subconjunto de estilos (aaaa) (com século).
- (2) Os valores padrão (style0 ou 100, 9 ou 109, 13 ou 113, 20 ou 120, e 21 ou 121) sempre retornam o século (yyyy).
- (3) entrada quando você converte em datetime; saída quando você converter dados de caractere.
- (4) projetado para uso de XML. Para conversão de datetime ou smalldatetime dados de caracteres de formato de saída é conforme descrito na tabela anterior.
- (5) Hijri é um sistema de calendário com muitas variações. SQL Server usa o algoritmo kuwaitiano.

Comment: mais uma vez Muito Obrigado Salvou meu dia!!!!!

Comment: Surgiu mais uma dúvida @Sorack.se baseando nessa query aqui ALTER VIEW temp_vertical_dashboard AS (
  SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, t.data, 101) AS data
    FROM tabela t
) ele vai converter o campo para tupo data mas vai apagar todas as colunas da minha view e como oeço para ele so atualizar nesse campo e nao apagar outros campos que já existe por favor?

Comment: @Kelvin É só colocar outro nome para o campo depois da cláusula `AS`

Comment: Valeu @Sorack deu tudo certo